# Load image into existing Mat

Tags: c++, c, opencv

Is there a way to load an image into an existing Mat? If not, is there a way to control where OpenCV allocates memory when calling cv::imread?

Comment: Why do you need to do that exactly? If you have a series of images you would like to process as if it were a video file, FFmpeg can do that... If not, then what is the use case here?

Comment: I'm using OpenCV to load images into my application. However, I'm using my own image class so I'm converting the OpenCV Mat into my own image class. I don't want to copy the image so I want a way to tell OpenCV where to load the image.

Comment: I see... OpenCV defines a `cv::imread_()` function that accepts a `cv::Mat` as parameter inside `loadsave.cpp`, but it's declared `static`, so you would need to modify the source code and recompile to access it.. I don't think there is an answer to this question otherwise :(

Answer (score 0):

I would simply make a constructor for your class that takes the input arguments of imread and loads (and allocates) the image directly into your class.

So something like this:

```
class myClass {
private:
    Mat img;
public:
    myClass(const string fileName) {
        this->img = imread(fileName);
    }
}
```